recycle bin in Dual Boot windows 11 and Ubuntu shared drive
I want to make my dual boot system share my data so I created a partition D: in windows
Now I want to mount and bind my document, downloads, and all folder with Ubuntu
I changed my /etc/fstab to this:-
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/17a02e14-370c-497b-8d22-ba028042ccb7 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0EA0-A281 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=12EEEBB7EEEB90F1   /mnt/SharedVolume       ntfs    defaults,uid=1000,gid=1,recycle 0 0
UUID=12EEEBB7EEEB90F1   /media/ntfs             ntfs-3g defaults,recycle 0 0
/mnt/SharedVolume/Documents /home/sumit/Documents   none    bind
/mnt/SharedVolume/Downloads /home/sumit/Downloads   none    bind
/mnt/SharedVolume/Music     /home/sumit/Music   none    bind
/mnt/SharedVolume/Pictures  /home/sumit/Pictures    none    bind
/mnt/SharedVolume/Videos    /home/sumit/Videos  none    bind

It was working before but now bind is not working.
I also want to use recycle bin when deleting my data without having to delete it permanently.

If I read this correctly you want to different OS to share the same trash-recycle bin?

Windows may turn its fast startup which sets hibernation flag, on Windows updates. Double check that fast startup is off. The Linux NTFS driver will not write into hibernated NTFS partitions.

everything is turned off and all and
i cant unmount that disk as well for some reason
by sudo umount -a

and what i want was to use my shared disk as it is used in windows
like
download, photos, videos all the of this's location is changed to D:\downloads ....
and when i delete some thing form it
it goes to recycle bin instead it deleting it permanently.
i want my ubuntu do be like this as well
i mounted my shared disk
and bind the /home/../downloads  to /mnt/SharedVolume/downloads
adding lines to  /etc/fstab as you can see
but there is only the option of permanetly delete files from that directory
which i dont want
